# How to read every second and third line of a text document in visual basic?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I'm having trouble trying to figure out how to read every first, second and third line of a text document that I generated with a program that I designed to append data to that same text file, basically using the File.AppendText, here is how the data looks like in a text document (namelist.txt):

```
John
49
Florida
1970
Elizabeth
50
Nebraska
1953
Mike
18
Vancouver
1993
Michelle
25
Berlin
1986
```

So basically my question is how do you read like every second or third line in order to display them in a list table? For example I want to read all ages displayed in the document, but I would have to read every second line using a for loop:

```
Try
   ageFile = File.OpenText("namelist.txt")

   For intCount = 2 to ageFile.EndOfStream
      strAge = ageFile.ReadLine()

      lstDisplay.Items.Add(strAge)
   Next
   ageFile.Close()
Catch
```

I'm not too sure if this is the right way and I also want to read like all the names and years, I kinda need help here, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
intCount = 0
While (strAge = ageFile.ReadLine()) IsNot Nothing
    If intCount Mod 4 = 1 Then
        //This will be every third row in the file
    End If
    intCount += 1
End While
```

Comment: sorry that didn't work out, I'm also not sure what the Mod is

Comment: Mod returns the remainder when the given value is dived by 3: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se0w9esz.aspx. In your case this will result in the value of 0  every third line

Comment: Ohh, for this code, does this like read the lines in the text docs in groups of 3 for example?

Comment: It doesn't read the lines in groups of 3 but it allows you to determin every third row. It reads all the rows and the IF statement will succeed on every third row, so then just put your relevant code inside the IF

Comment: It worked but it only my .ReadLine() only showed the first one (Florida), it didn't read the other ones, any help?

Comment: I updated the answer to explain how it works with a loop and changed the number to ensure it only handles the Age lines

Comment: thanks for the logic behind this, i'm dealing with "Null is ambiguous" and intCount++ "Expression is not a method" sorry this 2013 visual studio has changed so much that I can't use codes :(

Answer (score 0):

So you want to group every three consecutive lines together; that's fairly strightforward using LINQ.

(You tagged this C#, so presumably you don't mind a C# solution.)

```
var groups = File.ReadLines(path)
    .Select((line, index) => new { line, index })
    .GroupBy(item => item.index / 3, item => item.line);
```

Comment: Is there a Visual Basic way for this part?

Comment: @PatrickGamboa Yep, and seeing as you asked for a C# solution despite having a VB project, I assume you're capable of finding it on your own.  All of these methods are part of the .NET library which can be used from either language.  One point to pay attention to though is to ensure you use integer division when converting to VB, as that is essential to the solution used here.